# Comparison of Noir and Phantom

Tags: requiem-for-the-phantom, noir

Recently, I started to watch Noir and right now I am on the 10th episode. But it seems that there is a strong connection between Noir and Phantom. Indeed, they have both amnesiacs and they are assassins as well. My question is:

Which anime was influenced by another one first?

Comment: Phantom predates Noir by a year, so if there is any influence between them, it'd have to be Phantom influencing Noir.

Comment: @senshin You mean Manga or Tv series?

Comment: I've removed the part looking for similar titles as recommendation questions are off topic here

Comment: @Babgen The Phantom visual novel was released in 2000; the Noir anime aired in 2001.